# Ubuntu and Eclipse cannot find the latest Java version

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox, java, eclipse

I have an Ubuntu on VirtualBox and I just installed Eclipse. When I tried to start Eclipse, Eclipse claimed

> Version 1.6.0_35 of the JVM is not suitable for this product. Version: 1.7 or greater is required

I installed `openjdk-7-jre` and `openjdk-7-jdk` using `apt-get install` to satisfy Eclipse, then I restarted the virtual machine but Eclipse kept giving the same error.

I checked the java version with `java -version` and realized that Ubuntu seems to think that I am using 1.6 as well.

How can I fix this?

Note: I double checked that I installed the right version of Eclipse (64-bit)

Comment: #1.have you downloaded eclipse from software center or from the website?... #2. How did you install the jdk6 version? software center or website?

Comment: OP said this question solved their problem in a self-answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this I look it up and Java requires more than that I have not try this fix but here it is. Check out the page [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11877538/how-can-i-install-eclipse-and-java-sdk-on-ubuntu)

```
sudo apt-get install eclipse
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk openjdk-6-source openjdk-6-demo openjdk-6-doc openjdk-6-jre-headless openjdk-6-jre-lib
```

Execute this in your terminal. The first one installs eclipse if it is already installed it will just update it. (You will be asked to enter your password) and the second one installs all the Java stuff you may need!